# Plasma not running for specific user

Tags: kde, desktop-environment, software-updates, plasma, plasma5

My distro is **KDE Neon 5.24** and running with an **AMD Ryzen 7 5800X CPU** and **AMD RX 5700 GPU**.
I recently did a system upgrade after which my KDE Plasma shell stopped working properly.
The errors that I initially got were `ksplashqml closed unexpectedly` or `baloo-file-extractor closed unexpectedly`

Those errors appeared because the plasma shell isn't working. The problem only occurs on my main user. It works on other users on the system. I even created a new `test` user to try this and it was working fine there too.
The errors that I'm receiving when running `kstart5 plasmashell` on the broken user are:

```
Icon theme 'breeze' not found
Icon theme 'breeze-dark' not found
Icon theme 'breeze' not found
starting invalid corona "org.kde.plasma.desktop"
```

(Running `sudo -u brokenuser kstart5 plasmashell`, but it still has some issues with the themeing and general KDE settings, it's also starting it up in /tmp from what I understand)
Here is the list of things that I've tried so far and none of them solves my issue:

- Tried running `sudo -u brokenuser kstart5 plasmashell` (mentioned above)
- Removed KDE themes from the proper theme directory in the brokenuser's home directory
- Removed KDE config files from `.local`, `.config`, `.kde` (by renaming them)
- Reset all KDE themes for the user using `System Settings` by starting plasmashell as root and running the program under the brokenuser (`sudo -u brokenuser systemsettings5`)
- Reinstalled `plasma-desktop`, `plasma-workspace`, `plasma-framework` with `sudo apt install --reinstall plasma-desktop plasma-workspace plasma-framework`
- Removed entire `.local`, `.config`, `.kde` and `.cache` directories from the home directory to get new configuration files and settings (by renaming them)
- Copied entire `.local`, `.config`, `.kde` and `.cache` directories to the new `test` user to see if it will break its plasma shell too. It doesn't break anything, the user still functions properly
- Removed entire global KDE directories (by renaming them)

I have no idea what else to try. Is there another KDE folder that I am missing that could have some bad configuration in it? What id causing this?

Errors from `.xsession-errors` (not sure if this is happening after I close a plasmashell running with `sudo` or when I start a plasmashell running without `sudo`):

```
kdeinit5_wrapper: Warning: connect(/run/user/1000/kdeinit5__0) failed: : No such file or directory
Error: Can not contact kdeinit5!
```

General journalctl log

```
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop plasma_session[5702]: org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/geoclue-demo-agent.desktop" ("/usr/libexec/geoclue-2.0/demo>
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop plasma_session[5702]: org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/spice-vdagent.desktop" ("/usr/bin/spice-vdagent")
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop plasma_session[5702]: org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/at-spi-dbus-bus.desktop" ("/usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher>
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop plasma_session[5702]: org.kde.plasma.session: failed to parse "/etc/xdg/autostart/distro-release-notifier.desktop" for autostart
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop plasma_session[5702]: org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/home/brokenuser/.config/autostart/ckb-next.autostart.desktop" ("/usr/bin/ckb-n>
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop gwenview[5980]: Icon theme "breeze-dark" not found.
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop gwenview[5980]: Icon theme "breeze" not found.
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop plasma_session[5702]: org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/kup-daemon.desktop" ("/usr/bin/kup-daemon")
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop plasma_session[5702]: org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/snap-userd-autostart.desktop" ("/usr/bin/snap", "userd", "->
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop plasma_session[5702]: org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/etc/xdg/autostart/im-launch.desktop" ("/bin/sh", "-c", "if [ \"x$XDG_SESSION_>
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop plasma_session[5702]: org.kde.plasma.session: Starting autostart service  "/home/brokenuser/.config/autostart/konsole.autostart.desktop" ("/usr/bin/konsol>
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop dbus-daemon[2173]: [session uid=1000 pid=2173] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.kded5'
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop kup-daemon[6008]: kup.daemon: "Kup is not enabled, enable it from the system settings module. You can do that by running kcmshell5 kup"
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop kwin_x11[5744]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 1305, resource id: 85983237, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code:>
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop kded5[5996]: kf.service.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "KDEDModule" not found
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop konsole[6013]: Icon theme "breeze-dark" not found.
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop konsole[6013]: Icon theme "breeze" not found.
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop NetworkManager[1143]: <info>  [1645622073.1649] agent-manager: agent[8fb5c508aa6a36f4,:1.198/org.kde.plasma.networkmanagement/1000]: agent registered
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop kernel: traps: kded5[5996] trap int3 ip:7f080cd30295 sp:7ffc94b04ce0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.6400.6[7f080ccf4000+84000]
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop kded5[5996]: Installing the delayed initialization callback.
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop kded5[5996]: org.kde.libkbolt: Failed to connect to Bolt manager DBus interface:
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop kded5[5996]: org.kde.bolt.kded: Couldn't connect to Bolt DBus daemon
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop kwin_x11[5744]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 1309, resource id: 90177541, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor code:>
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop kded5[5996]: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
```

Things that show up with red color in journalctl from KDE related programs:

```
feb 23 15:14:32 monster-desktop kwin_x11[5744]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: Unrecognized RMLVO layout "de" was ignored
feb 23 15:14:32 monster-desktop kwin_x11[5744]: kwin_xkbcommon: XKB: Unrecognized RMLVO variant "qwerty" was ignored
...
feb 23 15:14:32 monster-desktop plasmashell[5800]: starting invalid corona "org.kde.plasma.desktop"
...
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop kup-daemon[6008]: kup.daemon: "Kup is not enabled, enable it from the system settings module. You can do that by running kcmshell5 kup"
...
feb 23 15:14:33 monster-desktop kded5[5996]: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
```

I also get some QXcbConnection errors:

```
feb 23 15:16:31 monster-desktop kwin_x11[5744]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 59579, resource id: 16780117, major code: 3 (GetWindowAttributes), minor >
feb 23 15:16:31 monster-desktop kwin_x11[5744]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 9 (BadDrawable), sequence: 59580, resource id: 16780117, major code: 14 (GetGeometry), minor code:>
feb 23 15:16:36 monster-desktop kwin_x11[5744]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 61513, resource id: 109051915, major code: 18 (ChangeProperty), minor cod>
feb 23 15:16:36 monster-desktop kwin_x11[5744]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 61556, resource id: 85983257, major code: 15 (QueryTree), minor code: 0
feb 23 15:16:36 monster-desktop kwin_x11[5744]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 61596, resource id: 85983277, major code: 15 (QueryTree), minor code: 0
```

Comment: I **believe** you launched the upgrade within your plasma session. Other users have had their configs correctly updated while yours have not been since being active. I know this **should** work but I am very old school, so I never upgrade anything from behind KDM/KDE sessions. Always upgraded from console running single user.

Comment: I did the update from the Discover software center. If that's the case, then why when I copy directories with KDE config files from the brokenuser to the test user, does that user still function properly?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have fixed itself after running an update with `pkcon update` command.
Still a very odd issue.